# csrftoken not being generated with $.cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, csrf-protection

I am trying to create a form dynamically and submit it in Javascript.

I am trying to add the csrftoken in the form by doing the following:

```
script(src='/lib/cookiecj/jquery.cookie.js')

var form = document.createElement("form");
form.setAttribute("method", "post");
form.setAttribute("action", path);

var csrftoken = $.cookie("csrftoken");
console.log(csrftoken);
var csrf_test_name = document.createElement("input");
csrf_test_name.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
csrf_test_name.setAttribute("name", "csrf_test_name");
csrf_test_name.setAttribute("id", "csrf_test_name");
csrf_test_name.setAttribute("value", csrftoken);

document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
```

But the the csrftoken being generated is `undefined`
and I end up in a 403 Error which says `invalid csrf token`

I am sure that the `jquery.cookie.js` is being loaded.

Any kind of help, will be deeply appreciated. Stuck on this since a lot of time.

Comment: If `$.cookie("csrftoken")` returns `undefined` it is likely that the client doesn't have a cookie with this key on their machine. Where are you setting the cookie?

Comment: @sdgluck: I did not set the cookie, I thought the default name is 'csrftoken'
How do I 'set' the cookie?

Comment: A CSRF token is typically sent by the server using the `Cookie` HTTP header.